# Sonar 4.5.1 with C# plugin 3.3 - How to check multiple assemblies with fxcop

Tags: sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-scan

We have a `Sonar 4.5.1` setup with `C# plugin version 3.3` installed. This server is shared by few projects. There is a .NET 4.6 project which has been started off recently and Jenkins 1.655LTS is the CI tool for the project. I have setup Jenkins `"SonarQube Scanner 2.4"` as I couldn't use `"MSBuild SonarQube Scanner"`. (Note: Versions of "MSBuild Sonar Scanner" available are not compatible with the C# plugin version)

I have configured fxcop configurations in Sonar properties (through Jenkins) as below

```
sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/
sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe
**sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=**"./Path/bin/Debug/Project.ShopWindow.Core.Contracts.dll"
```

Please suggest how to have more than one assembly scanned. I tried various ways (using , and space) but they don't work. Having more than one `**sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=**` is also not supported.

Comment: This really is much simpler with the [Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) (integrates natively with MSBuild and FxCop, no need to set such properties). You should [upgrade](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) your SonarQube, get the latest C# plugin and use it with the Scanner for MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I wish things were simpler and I could go with this option. But several other projects are currently using the Sonar Central Server and upgrading of Sonarqube and C# plugins wont happen very soon. But I am sure this is not a lone situation and someone else might have come across with these.